# Custom model attribute (column name) title in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes, title

Can I add custom model attribute titles, so forms could automatically render them instead of "prettied" column name?

For example I apply some method in my model, which defines attribute title:

```
imaginary_method_which_defines_attribute_title :description, "Aprašymas"
```

So I do not need to write title in every form label helper:

```
<%= f.label :description, "Aprašymas" %>
```

And form helper automatically uses attribute title which I declared in model:

```
<%= f.label :description %>
```

Renders...

```
<label for="foomodel_description">Aprašymas</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what you're really looking for internationalization.

Check out [Rails Internationalization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

As with most things in Rails, it's a pleasure :)

Comment: Thanks, I18n just popped in my mind after I've posted this question :D Telepathy...