# How do I set human readable attribute names in a rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, humanize

This seems like a really simple question -- when I'm using form_for or fields_for helpers to generate markup from my models, how can I modify my model to customize the string that appears for a particular attribute?

More or less the same question was asked before[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042841/custom-model-attribute-column-name-title-in-ruby-on-rails)], but the answer was 'internationalize', and that's not what I'm trying to do, I just want to override one or two humanized attribute names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom model attribute (column name) title in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042841/custom-model-attribute-column-name-title-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override `human_attribute_name` in your AR class. See this [mailing list post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/196094#854653)

Comment: Ah-ha -- this wasn't work for me when I used `<%= fields_for :my_model` but it does work when I do `<% fields_for MyModel.new` -- actionpack is looking for an actual instance to then look up the class and call the human_attribute_name class method.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you'll be able to override [human_attribute_name](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/human_attribute_name/class) in your model along the lines of (not tested)

```
def self.human_attribute_name(*args)
  if args[0].to_s == "my_attribute"
    return "My Attribute"
  end
  super
end
```

This value will be used in the labels unless you have corresponding translations, which have a higher priority.

Comment: Hey! I said that already :-) More usefully, you probably meant `def self.human_attribute_name` since the method is called on the AR class directly by ActionView.