# Human Attribute Names in Rails 3.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom model attribute (column name) title in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042841/custom-model-attribute-column-name-title-in-ruby-on-rails)

I've been using this solution in Rails 2.x forever:

```
   HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    :email => "E-mail address"
  }

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr)
    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
  end
```

but this causes bizarre errors when getting the `errors` from an ActiveRecord instance. What is the correct way to get nice, human-readable names in Rails 3.x?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the correct Rails 3 approach would be to use the [translation api](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models), but I'm using human_attribute_name as follows:

```
def self.human_attribute_name(attr, options = {})
  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
end
```

The call to super may be expecting the options argument to be there.

Comment: Cool that worked. I should've checked the API. Just FYI I'm using `    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super.split(" ").collect {|word| word.capitalize}.join(" ")` which is cute but trivial :)

Comment: Unless I'm misinterpreting what you're doing, I think super.titleize would do the same thing, that is, capitalize all the words.  "foo bar baz".titleize => "Foo Bar Baz"

Comment: +1. There's some reason I don't use titlelize, like that it's Rails-only and not usable in Ruby. But in this case, it's perfect.

Comment: FYI `titlize` has other side-effects like removing dashes and other "non title" characters

Answer (score 29):

Using human_attribute_name with the I18n framework is more simple I think :

In your view : User.human_attribute_name("email")

In your locale yml file :

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: E-mail address
```

Comment: You can use a symbol too:
`User.human_attribute_name(:email)`